# Django/WeasyPrint: Bangla Font Rendering Issue

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-templates, weasyprint

My Python Version 3.6+, Django version 1.11.6 and OS: Windows-10 64bit.

I am creating the PDF file with weasyprint within Django project. But the problem is Bengali font is not rendering. Please check this screenshot.
[image]

Now this is my views.py file

```
def get_pdf_file(request, customer_id, sys_type):
    sys_type = customer_id
    area = "pdf"
    site_credit = site_credit1
    time_now = timezone.now()
    customers = get_object_or_404(CustomerInfo, pk=customer_id)

    due_taka_track = customers.duetaka_set.all()

    if due_taka_track == None:
        due_taka_track = 0

    unpaid_taka = int(customers.customer_price -
                      customers.customer_due_taka_info)
    due_taka_track = customers.duetaka_set.all()

    sum_cost_taka = due_taka_track.aggregate(
        sp=Sum('customer_due')).get('sp', 0)

    if sum_cost_taka == None:
        sum_cost_taka = 0
    total_paid_taka = sum_cost_taka + customers.customer_due_taka_info

    payment_status = 'complete'
    payment_message = ' '
    remain_taka='Full Paid '
    remain_msg=''


    if customers.customer_due_taka_info < customers.customer_price:
        payment_status = 'incomplete'
        payment_message = 'সম্পূর্ন টাকা পরিষোধ করা হয়নি'
        remain_msg='টাকা বাকী আছে'
        baki_ase="পাওনা আছে "

        remain_taka = customers.customer_price - customers.customer_due_taka_info



    context = {'customers': customers,
    'sys_type': sys_type,
    'area': area,
    'site_credit': site_credit,
    'site_name': 'Moon Telecom',
    'sys_type': sys_type,
    'due_taka_track': due_taka_track,
    'total_paid_taka': total_paid_taka,
    'payment_message': payment_message,
    'time_now': time_now,
    'unpaid_taka': unpaid_taka,
    'payment_message': payment_message,
    'remain_taka': remain_taka,
    'sum_cost_taka': sum_cost_taka,
    'remain_msg': remain_msg}

    html_string = render_to_string('shop/pdf_invoice.html', context).encode(encoding="UTF-8")
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')

    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline; filename=invoice' + \
        str(customers.id)+customers.customer_uid + customers.customer_name + '.pdf'

    HTML(string=html_string).write_pdf(response)
    return response
```

and this is my html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-16">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">



    <title>invoice copy {% if customers.customer_name %}Customer Name:{{customers.customer_name}}{% else %}
    Name: দেওয়া হয়নি{% endif %} | {{customers.customer_uid}}</title>

<head>
    <style>
        @import url('https://fonts.maateen.me/siyam-rupali/font.css');
        table,
        th,
        td {
            border: 1px solid black;
        }

        th,
        td {
            padding: 5px;
            text-align: left;
        }
        p,th,td,th,tr{
            font-size:10px;line-height:12px
            font-family: 'SiyamRupali', sans-serif;
        }
        .border_sx {
            border-style: solid;
            border-width: 1px;
            padding: 5px;
            border-radius: 5px;
            display:block;
            width: 100%;
            margin-right:-100px;
            padding: 10px;

}


        #background{
    position:absolute;
    z-index:0;
    background:white;
    display:block;
    min-height:50%; 
    min-width:50%;
    color:yellow;
}

#content{
    position:absolute;
    z-index:0.1;
}

#bg-text
{
    color:lightgrey;
    font-size:70px;
    margin-top: 160px;

    margin-right: 40px;
    transform:rotate(320deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(300deg);
}

#bg-text-one
{
    color:lightgrey;
    font-size:20px;
    line-height: 25px;
    margin-right: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 800px;
    margin-top: -10px;
    transform:rotate(320deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(300deg);
}
    #fix_font
    {
        font-size: 13.5px;
    }

    table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

td, th {

    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {

}
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="background">
        <p id="bg-text">Moon Telecom</p>
        <p id="bg-text-one">Fulhata Bazar জাহাঙ্গীর সুপার মার্কেট, ব্রীজ রোড, ফুলহাতা বাজার, মোডেলগঞ্জ। 01717-051200(সুকান্ত বসু) 01828-163858(দোকান)</p>
    </div>

    <div id="content" class="border_sx">
        <div class="invoice_intro">
            <div class="site_title" style="text-align:center; margin:0 auto">
                <h1 style="font-size:10px;line-height:12px">ওঁ</h1>
                <p style="font-size:8px;line-height:10px">মা কালী সহায়</p>
                <h2 style="font-size:19px;line-height:13px;">মুন টেলিকম</h2>

                <div class="invoice_info_one" style="width:70%;margin:0 auto; text-align:center">
                    <p style=";">সকল প্রকার মোবাইল সেট, সীম কার্ড, মেমোরী কার্ড, MP-3, সোলার চার্জার, সোলার ফ্যান, মোবাইল ফোনের ব্যাটারী, চার্জার,
                        ক্যাচিং,কাভার,হেডফোন, রেবন, ডিসপ্লে এবং ইলেট্রিক মালামাল বিক্রেতা</p>
                </div>
                <div class="invoice_location">
                    <p>জাহাঙ্গীর সুপার মার্কেট, ব্রীজ রোড, ফুলহাতা বাজার, মোডেলগঞ্জ।</p>
                </div>
                <div class="invoice_contact">
                    <p>01717-051200(সুকান্ত বসু) 01828-163858(দোকান)
                        <b>Email:</b> moontelecom2008@gmail.com</p>
                </div>



                <hr>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="customer_part" style="width:40%;margin:0px left;display:block">

            <div class="customer_info">
                {% if customers.customer_name %}
                <p style="font-size:">Customer Name:
                    <b> {{customers.customer_name}}</b>

                </p>
                {% else %}
                <p> Name: দেওয়া হয়নি</p> {% endif %}

                <p style="font-size:x">Phone Number: {% if customers.customer_mobile_no %} {{customers.customer_mobile_no}} {% else %} No Mobile Number
                    {% endif%}
                </p>
                <p style="font-size:">Purchase Time: {{customers.customer_sell_date}}</p>
                <p style="font-size:">invoice id:
                    <b>{{customers.customer_uid}}</b>
                </p>
                <p>{{customers.product_warrenty}}</p>
            </div>
        </div>





        <div class="">
            <table style="border-style: solid;border-width: 0px;">

                <tr>
                    <th>Product Name</th>
                    <th colspan="">Price</th>
                    <th>Product Price (MRP)</th>
                    <th>ID or IME</th>
                    <th>Warrenty</th>
                    <th>QN</th>

                </tr>


                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <b>{{customers.customer_product_name}}</b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <b>Customer Price: {{customers.customer_price}}</b> TK
                        <i>{% if customers.customer_discount_taka %} 
                        ( Discount added {{customers.customer_discount_taka}} TK )
                        {% else%}
                        {%endif%}</i>
                    </td>
                    <td>{{customers.customer_product_mrp}} Taka * {{customers.customer_product_quantity}} (QN) </td>
                    <td>{{customers.customer_product_id}}</td>


                    <td>
                        {% if customers.customer_product_warrenty %} {{customers.customer_product_warrenty}} Months {% else %} No {% endif %}
                    </td>
                    <td>{{customers.customer_product_quantity}}</td>
                </tr>


                <th>
                    First Time Payment
                </th>

                <th>

                    {{customers.customer_first_time_payment}} TK
                    <span style="color:red">{{customers.customer_first_due_info}}</span>
                </th>

                <td>
                    {{customers.customer_sell_date}}
                </td>


                {% if due_taka_track %}



                <tr>
                    <th>SL</th>
                    <th>Taka</th>
                    <th>Paid Date</th>
                    <th>Due Info</th>

                </tr>

                <hr> {% for track in due_taka_track %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{forloop.counter}}</td>
                    <td>
                        <i>{{track.customer_due}}</i> TK</td>
                    <td>{{track.customer_due_date}}</td>
                    <td>{{track.customer_due_info}}</td>
                </tr>
                {% endfor %} {% else %} {% endif %} {% if sum_cost_taka %}
                <tr>

                    <td>Total Due Complete </td>

                    <th>{{sum_cost_taka}} TK</th>

                </tr>
                {% else %} {% endif %}





                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <b>Total Paid</b>
                    </td>

                    <th>


                        {% if payment_message %} 
                        {{customers.customer_due_taka_info}} TK

                        <span style="color:red">{{payment_message}}</span>
                        <br>



                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">{{remain_msg}} {{remain_taka}}TK</button>
                        {%else %} {{customers.customer_due_taka_info}} TK
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Payment Completed</button>

                        {% endif %}
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <table border="none!important" style="margin-top:10px;border:none!important">
                <tr>
                    <th style="text-align:left">Customer signature</th>
                    <th  style="text-align:right">Authorized signature</th>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>


        <div class="customer_notifications">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">


                        {% if customers.customer_conditions %}
                        <div class="warning">
                            <p>
                                <i>{{customers.customer_product_name}} {{customers.customer_conditions}}</i>
                            </p>
                        </div>

                        {% else %} {% endif %}

                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                            <div class="footer_info">
                                <p id="fix_font"><b>বিঃদ্রঃ ডেলিভারির সময় মাল বুঝিয়া নিবেন। পরে কোন আপত্তী গ্রহনযোগ্য নয়। (বিক্রিত মাল ফেরত হয় না) </h6>
                                <p>Print date: {{time_now}}</b></p>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>








        <div class="footer" style="display:block">
            <div class="footer_info">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                            <div class="footer_info">
                                <div class="copy_right">
                                    {% if site_credit %}
                                    <p>{{site_credit}}</p>
                                    {% else %} {% endif %}

                                </div>

                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


</body>

</html>
```

I changed UTF-8/UTF but this issue did not fix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I installed(Kalpurush) font on my PC. Then I added that font write_pdf variable.

```
HTML(string=html_string).write_pdf(response,stylesheets=[CSS(string='body,p,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,tr,td { font-family: Kalpurush !important }')])
```